# pycharm and jupyter notebook upload error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter, attributeerror

Every time I try to upload to localhost the jupyter file and I want to run, I get this error thrown:

```
[W 2023-09-23 19:13:59.137 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/contents/Users/X/Documents/TUD/X/Playground/CNN/MNIST/MNIST.ipynb?content=0&1695489239095 (2326da6ef10f4063902e3c00431a2359@127.0.0.1) 40.33ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree
[I 2023-09-23 19:31:26.838 ServerApp] Saving file at /MNIST.ipynb
[I 2023-09-23 19:31:26.875 ServerApp] Saving file at /MNIST.ipynb
[I 2023-09-23 19:31:26.876 ServerApp] Saving file at /MNIST.ipynb
Exception in thread AnyIO worker thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread AnyIO worker thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
Exception in thread AnyIO worker thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/Users/X/.local/share/virtualenvs/CNN-ty9g3gY6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 823, in run
  File "/Users/X/.local/share/virtualenvs/CNN-ty9g3gY6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 823, in run
    self.run()
  File "/Users/X/.local/share/virtualenvs/CNN-ty9g3gY6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 823, in run
    item = self.queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 181, in get
    item = self.queue.get()
    item = self.queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 181, in get
    item = self._get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 181, in get
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    item = self._get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 218, in _get
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 218, in _get
    item = self._get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 218, in _get
    return self.queue.popRight()
    return self.queue.popRight()
    return self.queue.popRight()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'popRight'
AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'popRight'
AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'popRight'
Exception in thread AnyIO worker thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/X/.local/share/virtualenvs/CNN-ty9g3gY6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 823, in run
    item = self.queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 181, in get
    item = self._get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/queue.py", line 218, in _get
    return self.queue.popRight()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'collections.deque' object has no attribute 'popRight'
```

Which seemed to me first like there are some issues with the depencies I'm using in my `pipenv`
So I updated all of them by using `pipenv update`
This is what I have now in my pip list:

```
(CNN) (base) Gabriels-iMac:MNIST gabrielteuchert$ pip list
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ---------
absl-py                      2.0.0
anyio                        4.0.0
appnope                      0.1.3
argon2-cffi                  23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings         21.2.0
arrow                        1.2.3
asttokens                    2.4.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
async-lru                    2.0.4
attrs                        23.1.0
Babel                        2.12.1
backcall                     0.2.0
beautifulsoup4               4.12.2
bleach                       6.0.0
cachetools                   5.3.1
certifi                      2023.7.22
cffi                         1.15.1
charset-normalizer           3.2.0
comm                         0.1.4
debugpy                      1.8.0
decorator                    5.1.1
defusedxml                   0.7.1
executing                    1.2.0
fastjsonschema               2.18.0
flatbuffers                  23.5.26
fqdn                         1.5.1
gast                         0.4.0
google-auth                  2.23.0
google-auth-oauthlib         1.0.0
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.58.0
h5py                         3.9.0
idna                         3.4
ipykernel                    6.25.2
ipython                      8.15.0
ipython-genutils             0.2.0
ipywidgets                   8.1.1
isoduration                  20.11.0
jedi                         0.19.0
Jinja2                       3.1.2
json5                        0.9.14
jsonpointer                  2.4
jsonschema                   4.19.1
jsonschema-specifications    2023.7.1
jupyter                      1.0.0
jupyter_client               8.3.1
jupyter-console              6.6.3
jupyter_core                 5.3.1
jupyter-events               0.7.0
jupyter-lsp                  2.2.0
jupyter_server               2.7.3
jupyter_server_terminals     0.4.4
jupyterlab                   4.0.6
jupyterlab-pygments          0.2.2
jupyterlab_server            2.25.0
jupyterlab-widgets           3.0.9
keras                        2.13.1
libclang                     16.0.6
Markdown                     3.4.4
MarkupSafe                   2.1.3
matplotlib-inline            0.1.6
mistune                      3.0.1
nbclient                     0.8.0
nbconvert                    7.8.0
nbformat                     5.9.2
nest-asyncio                 1.5.8
notebook                     7.0.4
notebook_shim                0.2.3
numpy                        1.24.3
oauthlib                     3.2.2
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
overrides                    7.4.0
packaging                    23.1
pandocfilters                1.5.0
parso                        0.8.3
pexpect                      4.8.0
pickleshare                  0.7.5
pip                          23.1.2
platformdirs                 3.10.0
prometheus-client            0.17.1
prompt-toolkit               3.0.39
protobuf                     4.24.3
psutil                       5.9.5
ptyprocess                   0.7.0
pure-eval                    0.2.2
pyasn1                       0.5.0
pyasn1-modules               0.3.0
pycparser                    2.21
Pygments                     2.16.1
python-dateutil              2.8.2
python-json-logger           2.0.7
PyYAML                       6.0.1
pyzmq                        25.1.1
qtconsole                    5.4.4
QtPy                         2.4.0
referencing                  0.30.2
requests                     2.31.0
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rfc3339-validator            0.1.4
rfc3986-validator            0.1.1
rpds-py                      0.10.3
rsa                          4.9
Send2Trash                   1.8.2
setuptools                   68.2.2
six                          1.16.0
sniffio                      1.3.0
soupsieve                    2.5
stack-data                   0.6.2
tensorboard                  2.13.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.7.1
tensorflow                   2.13.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.34.0
termcolor                    2.3.0
terminado                    0.17.1
tinycss2                     1.2.1
tornado                      6.3.3
traitlets                    5.10.0
typing_extensions            4.5.0
uri-template                 1.3.0
urllib3                      1.26.16
wcwidth                      0.2.6
webcolors                    1.13
webencodings                 0.5.1
websocket-client             1.6.3
Werkzeug                     2.3.7
wheel                        0.41.2
widgetsnbextension           4.0.9
wrapt                        1.15.0
```

Since I already updated pipenv, I don't think this might be problem. Yet I tried also everything else like, turning off ad blocker and firewall. Therefore it shouldn't be a communication issue, should it be?

Thanks in advance!